# .NET 8 MAUI: How to customize the look of the default Page.IsBusy ActivityIndicator on Android?

Tags: android, maui, .net-8.0

In .NET MAUI, each page has  an IsBusy property that, when true, shows a built-in activity indicator. I just want to know how to change the style of that specific indicator. I tried changing the style of ActivityIndicator in Styles.xaml, but that didn't do anything, so I assume I have to alter something in Platforms>Android>Resources>values but I don't know what.

In a default .NET 8 MAUI app running on Android, when you set IsBusy to True in the AppShell (or any other page), a blue activity indicator runs. I want to change the style of that. Ideally at least the colour.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: *I just want to know how to change the style of that specific indicator.*  Do you mean you want to change the style of a specific ActivityIndicator? What does it look like specifically? Could you give a schematic diagram? Try to use Handler of MAUI?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT I have added a picture to my original question. I am talking about the built-in activity indicator that runs while a page's IsBusy property is set to true. I will look into Handlers and see where that gets me. Thanks!

Comment: *I want to change the style of that. Ideally at least the colour.*  Like this: `<ActivityIndicator Color="Red" IsRunning="True"/>` ?

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT But that creates a new ActivityIndicator no? The Page class has a property called IsBusy and when that is set to true, an activity indicator (like in my screenshot) is shown without having to explicitly create one.

Comment: Wait, what's version of your emulator or real device, and .NET?  I add `IsBusy="True"`, 
but there's no built-in activity indicator :'(  My version: Pixel 5-API33(Android13.0) | .NET8 | VS: 17.92 Here is my [situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjFja.png).

Comment: I tried it with 2 separate projects (both on .NET 8), one with Android API 34, the other on API 33. I'm on .NET 8.0.200 and Visual Studio 2022 17.9.0. Both show the built-in spinner. Very strange that you don't get one at all!

Comment: It's weird, if I add a button, then add `IsBusy = !IsBusy;` to Button_Clicked, it can show the built-in activity indicator :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figure out it.

For built-in activity indicator, it is achieved through MessagingCenter(refer to [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/23171190fc32ba18c67d54f7b0dd9a3c487e8058/src/Controls/src/Core/Page/Page.cs#L706C31-L706C48)). On specific platform, e.g. Android, it adds and remove [ProgressBar](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/d03a2c66aa22b8a76eb3adec4235d17f917adf5f/src/Controls/src/Core/Platform/AlertManager/AlertManager.Android.cs#L293) to achieve the effect of showing and hiding.

So, get the native view and modify it:

```cs
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            IsBusy = !IsBusy;

#if ANDROID
            var progressLayout = Platform.CurrentActivity?.FindViewById(16908999) as Android.Widget.FrameLayout;
            var progressbar = progressLayout?.GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.ProgressBar;


           //when IsBusy is false, progressbar will be removed, will be null. So should make a judgment
            if (progressbar != null)
            {
                // set it to red
                var iconColorStates = Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList.ValueOf(Android.Graphics.Color.Red);
                progressbar.IndeterminateTintList = iconColorStates;
            }
#endif
```

Here is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc6vp.png).